# How to chain tokio read functions?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

Is there a way to chain the `read_*` functions in `tokio::io` in a "recursive" way ?

I'm essentially looking to do something like:

`read_until` x then `read_exact` y then write response then go back to the top.

In case you are confused what functions i'm talking about: https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.11/tokio/io/index.html

Comment: They are the read functions here: https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.11/tokio/io/index.html

Comment: Though I have read the doc for the functions, but it's quite unclear from the documentation how to actually chain them together properly

Comment: Edit your post and add the description there ;) You are not posting this for me, but for everyone else who might stumple upon your question

Comment: I assume most people that could answer the question wouldn't need the docs link :p... but, w/e

Comment: Don't assume things you don't know ;) Stackoverflow is a place for people who google for a thing and start digging around. The more you clarify your question, the more you can help people. You provided the documentation, so a person who reads this knows exactly the version you are using and the exact crate you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way.

[`read_until`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.9/tokio_io/io/fn.read_until.html) is returns a struct [`ReadUntil`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.9/tokio_io/io/struct.ReadUntil.html), which implements the [`Future`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.24/futures/future/trait.Future.html)-trait, which iteself provides a lot of useful functions, e.g. [`and_then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.24/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.and_then) which can be used to chain futures.

A simple (and silly) example looks like this:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_io; // 0.1.8 // 0.1.24

use futures::future::Future;
use std::io::Cursor;
use tokio_io::io::{read_exact, read_until};

fn main() {
    let cursor = Cursor::new(b"abcdef\ngh");
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; 2];
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        String::from_utf8_lossy(
            read_until(cursor, b'\n', vec![])
                .and_then(|r| read_exact(r.0, &mut buf))
                .wait()
                .unwrap()
                .1
        )
    );
}
```

Here I use a Cursor, which happens to implement the [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.9/tokio_io/trait.AsyncRead.html)-trait and use the `read_until` function to read until a newline occurs (between `'f'` and `'g'`).
Afterwards to chain those I use `and_then` to use `read_exact` in case of an success, use [`wait`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.24/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.wait) to get the `Result` unwrap it (don't do this in production kids!) and take the second argument from the tuple (the first one is the cursor).
Last I convert the `Vec` into a String to display `"gh"` with `println!`.

Comment: that isn't really what I'm looking for, as in, it misses the recursive part. I'm looking more for something like "Lines" where I can apply the function over and over to a stream of data, as in, whenever it reaches the end it goes back to the top, so to speak. But the ReadUntil and other structs returned by the read functions don't implement `Stream` in a way similar to lines.

Comment: If you may, I'm looking for something similar to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/75ftyj/how_can_i_write_a_basic_service_in_tokio/ But with the new tokio, rather than tokio-core and the old modules

Comment: Then please expand your answer! I read the question as such that you don't know how to chain `read_until` and `read_exact`. A "recusirve" way as such can't exist, because you can't call closures recursivly. Why didn't you posted that link (or the example) in your question, so I know what you are looking for?

Comment: Because If I could find an example I wouldn't be asking the question.... :/

Comment: The example above is using tokio-rs and I'm not even 100% sure it does what I intent to do (as in, it may close the connection)

Comment: Anyway, as far as I can tell wirting a Codec that sits over MIO directly seems to be the only way to do this at the moment... which is a tad bit silly. But, I'll leave the question open, maybe I'm missing something. Thank you for trying.